# edit products page wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

http://srihari.guru/?post_type=product

I am trying to edit this page so that instead of adding to cart it takes the user to more info right away, aka the individual products details page. I am struggling to figure out which php file to edit without removing the add to cart button also on the individual product page.

any help woudl really be appreciated.